# Clear attachment issues on AMD hardware

Tags: vulkan

My Vulkan application works flawlessly on both an integrated Intel HD620 and a Nvidia Quadro4000.
Validation layers are enabled and everything is just fine.

Then I moved to an ArchLinux server, using the AMDGPU driver with sea island support enabled to test on a R9 390X.
The Vulkan SDK (1.2.135.0) samples work as expected, but my application shows only garbage.

I reduced the issue to a minimal setup, with a single renderpass, a single subpass, no depth/stencil, a single color attachment,
no descriptor sets and trivial vertex and fragment shaders.

The code inside the render pass is the following:

```
VkClearAttachment catt = {
    .aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT,
    .colorAttachment = 0,
    .clearValue = { .color = { .float32 = { 1,0,1,1 } } }
}
VkClearRect rect = {
    .rect = { .offset = { 0,0 }, .extent = { width,height } },
    .baseArrayLayer = 0,
    .layerCount = 1
}
vkCmdClearAttachemnts(commandbuffer,1,&catt,1,&rect);
```

The above code produces the expected full screen magenta attachment.

now the weird part:

a) setting .offset or .extent  to **any** value (allowed by the renderpass) produces always this **same** output:

[image: output first run]

b) changing only the clear color to green and running the application again produces the following output:

[image: output second run]

I have no clue about what is going on.

Validation layers are silent, I checked back on the HD620 and the Quadro4000 and everything works as expected.
I switched to an amd HD7750, so to keep the AMDGPU driver, and I get the **same** wrong/blocky results as for the R9 390X.

Can it be a AMDGPU driver issue? Still, the SDK samples (Hologram) work as expected.

I have been checking every single line of code during the last 3 days, the blocky nature of the output points me to a possible tiling issue but.. everything is TILING_OPTIMAL.

Comment: Based on the information here I can't think of anything you might be doing wrong, so it would be worth filing a bug against the AMDGPU driver.

Comment: Question, are you positive you setup your image attachments to the clear enumerator and not to don;t care?

Comment: @Makogan yes of course, but I understand you ask. Turns out, there are seriuous incompatibilities with AMDGPU and pre-GCN3 cards. switching from RADV to AMDVLK as vulkan drivers solves the problems.